# XPages Extension library - select value in toolbar node

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I´m working on a new user interface for an existing database with Xpages. In the Notes Client the database has an action where the user can set the status for multiple documents. In a Prompt-box the user can choose the status and then the chosen status is set to all selected documents.

In my XPages interface I´ve created the action bar with the toolbar control from the extension library. When I use a hardcoded status, everything works fine, but I don´t know how I can show the user a value picker or something similar, when he clicks on the toolbar action.

Any other concepts to solve my problem are also appreciated. Maybe there are other (better) ways to implement this process in Xpages.

Thanks in advance

Joerg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could use a dropdown button in the action bar with the various options. If they need to be configurable you might opt for a repeat node for the dropdown values. You don't want to have popups in a web application - that's a client application UI style